# CoreData updating an NSManagedObject more than once saves several copies?

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobject, insert-update

I have 90 CoreData entities called "ItemModel" with 2 attributes 'uid', 'description', where each of the item is inserted as an NSManagedObject:

```
NSManagedObject *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"ItemModel" inManagedObjectContext: AFYDelegate.managedObjectContext];
```

The first server call assigns the 'uid' to each of the 90 items fetched above for key "uid". The context is not saved here.

On a later second server call, I like to update 'description' for the 90 items, for **each** of the NSManagedObject using indexPath - by fetching and passing each object to the following method and saving the context:

```
[self updateItemToDataModel:object withData: description];

....
....

- (void)updateItemToDataModel:(NSManagedObject *) object withData:(NSString *)data
{   
    [object setValue:data  forKey:@"description"];

    NSError * error = nil;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
       //Handle any error with the saving of the context
       NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```

The above works fine in updating CoreData BUT after closing the Simulator and running the code again, there will be two duplicates for each item with the same 'uid' and 'description'. This means I have 180 items now. Repeatedly closing and running the code creates more and more items.

I tried removing updateItemToDataModel method, resetting the Simulator and it works fine with 90 items.

I'm new to CoreData if someone can help. What's wrong with my code if I only wished to update existing items?

Comment: How are you retrieving your 'object'? Do you have that code?

Comment: Retrieving object by indexPath in a UICollectionView and NSFetchedResultsController  -  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] lastObject];  
    NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting a new object into the MOC (managed object context) each time--instead of doing a fetch and finding an existing instance of the object you wish to update.

To fetch the existing object you might execute a fetch request like so...

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid == %@", uidToMatch];
NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ItemModel" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
NSError * error = nil;
NSArray * results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if ([results count]) {
    // you may need to handle more than one match in your code...
    // you could also set a fetch limit of 1 and guarantee you only get the first object, eg: [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];
}
else {
    // no results
}
```

You might want to wrap that in a helper function so you can re-use it.  And read up on NSFetchRequest, NSPredicate and writing predicates in order to do fancier fetch requests.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Nicholas! Just to clarify the NSArray results is returning NSManagedObject class objects and I just do setValue? And when should I correctly save the self.managedObjectContext? - is it at ViewDidUnload of RootViewController or AppDelegate applicationWillTerminate?

Comment: It's returning an array of all the managed objects which match the specified entity name and the specified predicate.  In this case, your "ItemModel" object(s).  Deciding when to save your data is up to you.  Doing a save can be expensive so you want to wait until your user is done making changes (eg: when dismissing your edit interface).  You probably don't want to wait until your app is closed to save--because if it crashes you'll lose all your data.  (And incidentally, never rely on viewDidUnload or applicationWillTerminate to be called--there is no guarantee they will ever be called.)